# consecutive submits with libcURL (C/C++)

Tags: c, curl, submit, form-submit, libcurl

I'm new using libcURL and have a problem to do a task.

I need to do a two submits consecutives to change a textbox.

First: The web have a select box (group) and a submit button.

Second: After de first submit you obtain an specific page with

That my code, but doesn't work(both submits):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <curl/types.h>
#include <curl/easy.h>

int main(void)
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    struct curl_httppost *formpost = NULL;
    struct curl_httppost *lastptr = NULL;
    struct curl_slist *headerlist = NULL;
    static const char buf[] = "Expect:";

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL); 

    curl_formadd(&formpost, &lastptr, CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "group", CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, "ImageSource", CURLFORM_END);
    curl_formadd(&formpost, &lastptr, CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "submit", CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, "Select group", CURLFORM_END);
    curl_formadd(&formpost, &lastptr, CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "root_ImageSource_I0_Name", CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, "weboCam", CURLFORM_END);
    curl_formadd(&formpost, &lastptr, CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "submit", CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, "Save", CURLFORM_END);

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    headerlist = curl_slist_append(headerlist, buf);

    if(curl) 
    {
      /* First set the URL that is about to receive our POST. This URL can
         just as well be a https:// URL if that is what should receive the
         data. */ 
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://192.168.0.90/admin/config.shtml");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "xxxx:xxxx");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headerlist);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPPOST, formpost);   

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        long http_code = 0;

        curl_easy_getinfo (curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &http_code);

        if (http_code == 200 && res != CURLE_ABORTED_BY_CALLBACK)
        {
            cout << "Todo ha ido perfecto." << endl;         //Succeeded
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Ha habido un error." << endl; //Failed
        }

        curl_formfree( formpost );

        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
```

Another problem: The code compiles and shows that everything goes right but really only show the default page code `http://192.168.0.90/admin/config.shtml`

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand. If you want two submits, why does your program only call curl_easy_perform() once?

Comment: becuase first of all i want to see if the the first two curl_formadd works. In the original code the last two curl_formadd are commented.

Answer (score 1):

First step done.

This code do the first step.

```
char *data1="group=ImageSource";
    char *data2="root_ImageSource_I0_Name=weboCam";

    curl = curl_easy_init();

    if(curl) 
    {
        // Put the original page
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://192.168.0.90/admin/config.shtml");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "root:root");       
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, data1);
```

Take selection of the first select.
[image]

After doing this I want to modify this textbox
[image]

Summarize: I want to change a textbox in the second level of a page. The problem is libcurl on the second `easy_perform` return to the top level.